# Hibernate/Spring. How to override hibernate's default SQLExceptionConverter?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to override the `SQLExceptionConverter` in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways:

1. You can create your custom hibernate dialect that will extend some standard hibernate dialect and override the method [buildSQLExceptionConversionDelegate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#buildSQLExceptionConversionDelegate--).
2. It is also possible to plug in a custom implementation via the `hibernate.jdbc.sql_exception_converter` configuration property.

See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-exception-handling) and [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-exception-handling) part of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Having a hard time with this right now.

Comment: Still seem to fail to initialize. I have the `hibernate.properties`, and see it in spring boot logs with `HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.jdbc.sql_exception_converter=my.com.Clazz}` with no further error, but I do not see any initialization during debug - only the `StandardSQLExceptionConverter`.

Comment: I am literally bumping into this brick wall - http://useof.org/java-open-source/org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate

Comment: Try to use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.sql_exception_converter` as it's explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.jpa-properties).

Comment: Tried that, but no - the class(even if I input a false name) isn't initialized and nothing is informing about it. I would think that this is something of a custom library or some config, but the only things that the POM has are spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ojdbc8(oracle).

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Didn't configure it much. Only the 'spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' is noted. From the debug it seems to be Oracle12 dialect.

Comment: But I'm not entirely sure how it's 'picked up'. I'm using `EntityManager's`(autowired, so assume Spring is forming it) `createStoredProcedureQuery` to make a call to a procedure with a `ref_cursor` output. I would assume that Spring should take care of things and digest both the properties and the converter class, to which I pointed, but seems like it just doesn't(shows in the logs that it was consumed and etc, but nothing more).

Comment: What spring boot version do you use?

Comment: 2.3.0. A bit old, but not that old.

Comment: Tried with the latest Spring boot and Hibernate - same thing